# Как изменить цвет фона в three.js с помощью dat.GUI?

Tags: javascript, three.js

у меня есть вот такой код

```
var option_default = function() {
this.colr_scene = '#C8C7C7';
};
var option_array = new option_default();  
var opt_none ;   
var gui = new dat.GUI({ autoPlace: false }); 
var action_colr_scene = gui.addColor(option_array_ise, 'colr_scene');

action_colr_scene.onChange(function(opt_none){renderer.setClearColor.color.setHex(opt_none.replace("#", "0x"));});

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor (0xC8C7C7 );
```

Проблема в том что у меня не как не получается изменить цвет в setClearColor 
Я уже пробовал кучу разных способов

```
 №1

  action_colr_scene.onChange(function(opt_none){renderer.setClearColor.color.setHex(opt_none.replace("#", "0x"));});
 №2

  action_colr_scene.onChange(function(opt_none){renderer.setClearColor.setHex(opt_none.replace("#", "0x"));});
 №3

 renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x444400));
 action_colr_scene.onChange(function(opt_none){renderer.getClearColor().setHex(opt_none.replace("#", "0x"));});
 №4

 renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x444400));
 var cotl =option_array_ise.colr_scene.replace("#", "0x") ; 
 renderer.getClearColor().setHex(cotl)
 №5

  var colt = new THREE.Color();
  var cotl =option_array_ise.colr_scene.replace("#", "0x") ; 
  colt.setHex(cotl)
  action_colr_scene.onChange(function(opt_none){colt.setHex(opt_none.replace("#", "0x"));});
  renderer.setClearColor(colt);
```

Но нечего не помогает 
кто не будь знает как изменить параметр color в setClearColor
Поскольку у меня кончаются идеи

Comment: Цвет фона так же можно изменить с помощью `scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xff00ff);`.

Answer (score 1):

`dat.GUI()` вполне понимает hex-значения цветов.

То есть, можно создать объект `color` со свойством `value` в виде hex-значения для цвета и все будет прекрасно работать:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(box);

var color = {
  value: 0x000000
}

var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.addColor(color, "value").name("background").onChange((value) => {
  renderer.setClearColor(value);
});

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  time = clock.getElapsedTime();
  box.rotation.y = time * 0.251;
  box.rotation.x = time * 0.314;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.3/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Вариант с `scene.background`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(box);

var c = new THREE.Color(0x000000); // задаем цвет
var color = {
  value: c.getHex() // получаем hex-здначение цвета и записываем его в объект
}

scene.background = c; // устанавливаем фон равным цвету

var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.addColor(color, "value").name("background").onChange((value) => {
  c.set(value); // меняем значение заданного цвета
});

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  time = clock.getElapsedTime();
  box.rotation.y = time * 0.251;
  box.rotation.x = time * 0.314;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.3/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @zeni1agent Чисто из любопытства: помогло? :)